# Android NDK Make File and Maven Build Issues

Tags: maven, compilation, android-ndk, build-process

Let me just say that I'm pretty new to Android NDK and so, I've been trying to go through Androids documentation on it. I've come across some issues with it when trying to utilize it in Maven (via plugins). My maven plugins snippets are below as well as my Android.mk file.

pom.xml (plugins portion):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-AguiceAnnotationDatabasePackageName=my.package.name</compilerArgument>
        <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>javah</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <javahClassNames>
                    <javahClassName>my.package.name.MyClass</javahClassName>
                </javahClassNames>
                <javahVerbose>true</javahVerbose>
                <javahPath>$(THE_JAVA_PATH)\bin\javah.exe</javahPath>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <manifest>
            <debuggable>true</debuggable>
            <usesSdk>
                <minSdkVersion>17</minSdkVersion>
                <targetSdkVersion>18</targetSdkVersion>
            </usesSdk>
        </manifest>
        <apk>
            <debug>true</debug>
        </apk>
        <extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates>
        <dex>
            <coreLibrary>true</coreLibrary>
            <jvmArguments>
                <jvmArgument>-Xmx2048m</jvmArgument>
            </jvmArguments>
        </dex>
        <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${to.ndk.libs}</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
        <ndkOutputDirectory>${to.ndk.objs}/local</ndkOutputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-ndk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>ndk-build</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>${project.artifactId}</target>
                <finalLibraryName>${project.artifactId}</finalLibraryName>
                <ndkPath>$(THE_NDK_PATH)</ndkPath> 
                <makefile>jni/Android.mk</makefile>
                <applicationMakefile>jni/Application.mk</applicationMakefile>
                <architectures>${arch}</architectures>
                <additionalCommandline>${ndk.args}</additionalCommandline>
                <librariesOutputDirectory>${to.ndk.libs}</librariesOutputDirectory>
                <objectsOutputDirectory>${to.ndk.objs}</objectsOutputDirectory>
                <headerFilesDirectives>
                    <headerFilesDirective>
                        <directory>${basedir}/jni</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**\/*.h</include>
                        </includes>
                    </headerFilesDirective>
                    <headerFilesDirective>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/native/javah</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**\/*.h</include>
                        </includes>
                    </headerFilesDirective>
                </headerFilesDirectives>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My directory structure is as follows MyRoot -> jni - > (c/cpp files). And of course the standard directory structure for java files. My Android.mk file is the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := my-lib

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyClass1.cpp \
     MyFile1.c \
     MyClass2.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../target/native/javah

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions

LOCAL_CFLAGS += \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_ATOMIC_C_PLUS_PLUS_11_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_CAN_BUS_INTERFACE_ROUTER_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_CAN_BUS_CREATED_BY_CONFIGURATION_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_CAN_BUS_TC_SERVICE_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_CRC_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_EXCEPTIONS_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_FILE_SUPPORT_CRT_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_FLOAT_64_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_LOG_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_MUTEX_PTHREAD_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_POSIX_SIGNAL_HANDLER_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_RANDOM_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_SECURITY_UNSET_INTENTIONALLY_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_THREAD_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_TRACE_STDIO_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_TCP_IP_ \
    -D _NX_FEATURE_XML_PARSER_ \
    -D NX_CUSTOMER_FAR \
    -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
    -D HAVE_FTRUNCATE=1 \
    -D HAVE_GETCWD=1 \
    -D HAVE_GETPAGESIZE=1 \
    -D HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 \
    -D HAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_MALLOC=1 \
    -D HAVE_MEMCHR=1 \
    -D HAVE_MEMMOVE=1 \
    -D HAVE_MEMORY_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_MEMSET=1 \
    -D HAVE_MKDIR=1 \
    -D HAVE_MMAP=1 \
    -D HAVE_MUNMAP=1 \
    -D HAVE_NETDB_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_PTRDIFF_T=1 \
    -D HAVE_RMDIR=1 \
    -D HAVE_SELECT=1 \
    -D HAVE_SOCKET=1 \
    -D HAVE_STDDEF_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_STDINT_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_STDLIB_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_STRINGS_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_STRING_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_STRPBRK=1 \
    -D HAVE_STRRCHR=1 \
    -D HAVE_STRSPN=1 \
    -D HAVE_STRTOUL=1 \
    -D HAVE_STRTOULL=1 \
    -D HAVE_SYS_PARAM_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_TERMIOS_H=1 \
    -D HAVE_UNISTD_H=1

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := $(ANDROID_MAVEN_PLUGIN_LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES)    
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := $(ANDROID_MAVEN_PLUGIN_LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Important: Must be the last import in order for Android Maven Plugins paths to work
include $(ANDROID_MAVEN_PLUGIN_MAKEFILE)
```

So the error I'm getting Is the following:

```
...\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd -C ...\MyRoot APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=jni/Application.mk NDK_TOOLCHAIN=x86_64-4.9 APP_ABI=x86_64 V=1 -B NDK_DEBUG=1 NDK_LIBS_OUT=...\MyRoot\target\ndk-libs NDK_OUT=...\MyRoot\target\ndk-obj MyRoot

make.exe: *** No rule to make target `MyRoot'.  Stop.
```

I'm not sure why MyRoot is even being used. And when I do the command manually wihtout the 'MyRoot' the build process starts but it doesn't seem to use any of my include files listed in my Android.mk file (LOCAL_C_INCLUDES).

Its probably something silly but I'm at a lost here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your command you have a floating 'MyRoot'. I'm pretty sure removing that will resolve this error.

```
...\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd -C ...\MyRoot \
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=jni/Application.mk \
NDK_TOOLCHAIN=x86_64-4.9 APP_ABI=x86_64 V=1 -B NDK_DEBUG=1 \
NDK_LIBS_OUT=...\MyRoot\target\ndk-libs \
NDK_OUT=...\MyRoot\target\ndk-obj MyRoot # this MyRoot is unnecessary
```

You will also find that many of these options (APP_ABI, NDK_TOOLCHAIN, etc.) are unnecessary if your Application.mk and directory structure are set up correctly.

Comment: Yes, and thats the problem. I mentioned if I remove it it works aside from the include errors. Using Maven and the Android.mk how do I get this out of there automatically? This needs to be automated

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear which 'MyRoot' you were removing. Can you post the error you get if you remove 'MyRoot'?

Comment: Its just compile errors since its not looking at header files in LOCAL_C_INCLUDES. I think thats the next step, but for now it would be nice if I could get that MyRoot off of the end of the automated build process

Comment: either something in the plugin or .mk file that I am doing wrong I would think.